# File path is working in NetBeans but not in built JAR file

Tags: java, file, netbeans

I have a file holding default information that I use to load the textFields of my application. I looked up how to get this built into my jar file when I build and I was told to put it in the source packages and it would be brought along, so I have done that.

File Structure:

```
Project
   -Source Packages
       -src
           ~Java Classes
       -defaultFiles
           ~Defaults.txt
```

The code I am trying to use is this:

```
BufferedReader in;
try {
    URL resourceURL = FuelProperties.class.getResource("/defaultFiles/Defaults.txt");
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(resourceURL.getPath()));
}
```

And this works perfectly when I run it through NetBeans but when I build the project and try to run it from the jar file it is not grabbing the file.

I have verified that the default file is being built and exists in the same file structure shown above.

If you can help me out with this I would be extremely grateful as I have no idea what is keeping this from working. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing that /src/defaultFiles is actually in your jar?

Comment: That's what I'm lead to believe, as in my dist folder (which is where the program builds to) there is only the jar file and a lib folder. And the lib folder only contains library jars.

Comment: Well, there's no reason not to check the jar to see if the files are indeed in there :)  Just use jar xvf <jarname>.jar to dump it all out.  But as Dennis R. said, you can't load files within jars this way.  You need to use one of the getResource methods of the class loader that contains the jar.

Comment: use absolute paths..where is your jar placed?

Comment: I don't want to use one set absolute path, as I would like the application to work on any computer, placed in any folder. The JAR is built to the projects 'dist' folder as I believe is standard for NetBeans projects. The file is definitely inside that JAR file, but somehow this method is not correctly accessing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after searching through a couple dozen questions. It turns out that you can only get a `InputStream` of the data within a file within your JAR not a `File` object like I was attempting to do. 
(If you want the `File` object you just have to extract the files from the JAR in your program and then you have access to it.)

So the code that got my problem to work was simply replacing this:

```
URL resourceURL = FuelProperties.class.getResource("/defaultFiles/Defaults.txt");
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(resourceURL.getPath()));
```

With this:

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/defaultFiles/Defaults.txt")));
```

And now it is working both inside NetBeans and in the Built JAR file.

Comment: I think it make sense, gonna try this, im using files and on the jar im receiven NPE, so I will change it for getResourceAsStream, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have to lookup in the classpath, not on the disk.
The API to use is :

```
URL resourceURL : this.getClass().getResource("relative path in the classpath");
```

Once you have the url you can open a stream, etc.

EDIT : in the main method, you of course need to replace

```
this.getClass()
```

by

```
ClassName.class
```

Comment: getResourceAsStream(String path) can also be very convenient as it returns the input stream directly.

Comment: Indeed but it is a one shot : the choice can be done depending on whether one needs to read the resource many times.

Comment: @DenisR. I have tried using your method and I've once again got it working in NetBeans but when I build and run the jar it is still not loading the files. I used Pleepleus advice and checked the jar to make sure the file is in there and it is, so I'm not sure what's not working here. :/

Comment: @Alex To test, here is the procedure :
Unzip you jar and see if there is a file with the following path in it : defaultFiles/Defaults.txt (or the file you use in getResource)
if no, you have the reason why it is not working
Note : in getResource, if the path starts with / it is absolute in the jar, if not starting with / it is RELATIVE to the package of the class on which you call getResource
For details, see here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

Comment: @DenisR. I've checked it several time, there is indeed a file with the absolute path of "/defaultFiles/Defaults.txt" or the relative path of "../defaultFiles/Defaults.txt" both of those options will work perfectly in NetBeans deployments, but both of them still fail when built. :S

Comment: @Alex Have you checked the case of the letters (on windows, the file system APIs often do not care about case sensitivity and maybe when running inside NetBeans, it is not building a jar but only executing with .class files on disk)

Comment: @DenisR. I checked and the Casing is identical in the extracted jar files as I have in my program. Good idea to check though